# How to downgrade PHP version on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, php-7

I've been having issues with my webapp ever since heroku upgraded to PHP 7.2.0. How can I downgrade to a 7.0.* version of PHP on heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku currently [supports PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-runtimes).

You can [select your runtime in your `composer.json` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#selecting-a-runtime), e.g.

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0"
  }
}
```

to select the latest version of PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

A little gotcha, make sure you commit in the composer.lock file after setting the php version in your composer.json:

```
composer update
```